# Angular 8 - Unable to set headers to HttpRequest

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Boot,Spring security and Angular 8.
I am trying to manually send an Authorization header that will be authenticated by spring security.
I also have problems while savind the cookies received.Every api response should have an JSESSIONID cookie that is not set in the browser.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class TestController{

  @PostMapping("/test")
  public String test() {
      System.out.println("TEST");
      return "TEST";
  }
}
```

Web Security Configuration

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.csrf().disable()
              .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
              .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
              .and()
              .httpBasic();
    }
```

Angular request (http:HttpClient)

```
  testMethod() {

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'jwt-token'
      })
    };
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/test', null, httpOptions).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      }
    );
  }
```

Request headers

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,ro-RO;q=0.9,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
```

Adding new headers worked with postman.

UPDATE:
This is what i see in the network tab:
[image]

[image]

Comment: the headers you're showing are the headers of the pre-flight OPTIONS request. You need to look at the headers of the actual POST request sent after that one. But why do you configure CORS for localhost:4200? Once the application is deployed, your requests will never come from localhost:4200. Use https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server, and don't bother with CORS.

Comment: I am still learning about spring in general and i didn't know what to do with cors.To check the headers i used the debugger.I put a breakpoint in the BasicAuthenticationFilter provided by spring-security.After i added some dummy header with Postman, i could see it on the request parameter on doFilterInternal.If i try with Angular, the added headers do not appear.

Comment: Look at the requests being sent in your browser dev tools (in the network panel). Postman doesn't need to send pre-flight request, because it's not a JS app running in the browser. Your Angular code needs to, because it is a JS app running in the browser.

Comment: I have updated the post with informations in the network panel.If the problem is with the pre-flight request, what can i do to fix it?Would proxying to the backend help?

Comment: If you use CORS only to deal with your development setup, and not for production (as it seems you are), then yes, don't bother with CORS, and use proxying as I recommended in my first comment. This will have the additional advantage to make the development setup similar to the production one. The error you get is a 401, which means that your server rejects the preflight request because it considers it as needing authentication.

Comment: The preflight request is rejected because it does not contain an auth authorization header.Is there a way to add this header to the preflight request too?

Comment: No, I don't think so. If the server ants to deal with CORS, then it should not reject the pre-flight request, but only the following ones. But again, all this wouldn't be necessary if you didn't have CORS.